# Variable always being set to 0 despite conditional blocks

Tags: php

The following block of code is an attempt to give some feedback for what a user may be inputting incorrectly and that side of it is working alright.

The part I am having trouble with is the else block. It seems to always set the `$MaxNum` variable to `0`. If I remove the declaration from  the else block it works fine, although obviously doesn't allow my code above to validate the input. I am probably overlooking something quite basic so any help would be great.

```
global $MaxNum, $TheNum;
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['maxnum'])){
        $error[] = "<p>Please enter at least something!";
        if($_POST['maxnum'] == 0){
            $error[] = "<p>Zero doesn't count!";
        }
    }
    if (!is_numeric($_POST['maxnum'])){
        $error[] = "<p>You didn't enter a number!";
    }

    if (is_numeric($_POST['maxnum'])){
        if(($_POST['maxnum'])>2147483647){
            $error[] = "<p>2.14 Billion jellybeans is a little excessive, right?";
        }
    }
    else{
        $MaxNum = $_POST['maxnum'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using elseif blocks instead of 3 separate ifs, otherwise it's going to check each one.

Comment: Please update the question and provide the error.

Comment: I think you have put your `else` block in wrong place. You probably want to put it after `if(($_POST['maxnum'])>2147483647)`, but you have put it after `if (is_numeric($_POST['maxnum']))` instead.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I've answered my own question below, found a fix this morning. Stack won't let me accept my answer until tomorrow though, cheers @NicoHaase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used @robbert van den Bogerd's tips to clean up my if statements and then implemented that. Still had the issue of the input being passed as there was nothing stopping that.

Created a new variable called $ValidInput and used it to hold a bool.
Through the checking I set it to False if it met any conditions.
Then at the end of the checks I attach the input to $MaxNum if $ValidInput remains True through the checking, if it made it to that point and was True it must meet our requirements.

```
global $MaxNum, $TheNum, $ValidInput;

$ValidInput = True;

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

    if (empty($_POST['maxnum'])) {
            $error[] = "<p>Please enter at least something!</p>";
            $ValidInput = False;
        }

        if(empty($_POST['maxnum']) && (!is_numeric($_POST['maxnum']))) {
            $error[] = "<p>Please enter a number!</p>";
            $ValidInput = False;
        }

        if($_POST['maxnum'] == 0) {
            $error[] = "<p>Zero doesn't count!</p>";
            $ValidInput = False;
        }

        if (!is_numeric($_POST['maxnum']) && (!empty($_POST['maxnum']))) {
            $error[] = "<p>That's not a number!</p>";
            $ValidInput = False;
        }

        if (is_numeric($_POST['maxnum']) && $_POST['maxnum'] > 2147483647) {
            $error[] = "<p>Anything over 2.14 Billion jellybeans is a little excessive, right?";
            $ValidInput = False;
        }

        if($ValidInput == True){
        $MaxNum = $_POST['maxnum'];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some tips:

- Try to use functions and early returns in your code, it makes your flow easier.
- Try to use less nested if statements and use `else if`

An example with function and early returns:

```php
global $MaxNum, $TheNum;

function handleFormSubmit(): string
{
    if (!isset($_POST['Submit']) || !isset($_POST['maxnum'])) {
        return "<p>Please enter at least something!</p>";
    }

    if(empty(['maxnum'])) {
        return "<p>Please fill in a number</p>!";
    }

    if($_POST['maxnum'] == 0) {
        return "<p>Zero doesn't count</p>!";
    }

    if (!is_numeric($_POST['maxnum'])) {
        return "<p>You didn't enter a number!";
    }

    if (is_numeric($_POST['maxnum']) && $_POST['maxnum'] > 2147483647) {
        return "<p>2.14 Billion jellybeans is a little excessive, right?";
    }

    $MaxNum = $_POST['maxnum'];

    return '';
}

$errorMessage = handleFormSubmit();
```

Comment: With `empty($_POST['maxnum'])` and `return` the `$_POST['maxnum'] == 0` will never be met.

Comment: Correct, I would remove this message actually, but it's just an example..

Comment: @RobbertvandenBogerd thankyou for the detailed response.  I am just a little worried that it looks like $MaxNum will be set no matter what is input, is that right? Or will it only be set if the input passes all the ifs?